# SQL List of Values 00:00 to 24:00

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm creating a select list based on a SQL Query in my Oracle APEX page.

I want it to show these time values :

```
00:00
00:01
00:02
.
..
...
.
.
23:59
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONNECT BY` for  Oracle 10+

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (LEVEL-1)/24/60, 'HH24:MI')
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24*60
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.
I've just copied and pasted code when it comes to connect by, any chance you could explain in detail what happens in the query you wrote above?

Comment: We can use `LEVEL` with the `SELECT CONNECT BY` statement to organize rows from a database table into a tree structure. `LEVEL` returns the level number of a node in a tree structure. The root is level 1, children of the root are level 2, grandchildren are level 3, and so on. 
So in our case we use `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= N ` for getting rows with the sequence of values. For limit values we use the number of minutes per day `24*60`

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, helped me a lot